# How to detect non-intrusive incoming call in unity on iOS 14?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, phone-call

Earlier I used `OnApplicationFocus` and `OnApplicationPause` methods inside Unity to detect any calls while game is running and pause it. On iOS 14 with new non-intrusive calls these methods are not working, even if user puts device to an ear and screen turns off. Is there a way to detect such calls in Unity or with a native plugin? I'm using Unity 2019.2.21.